# Import shared protobuf package into different protobuf packages

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java, protobuf.js

I'm designing some `protobuf` schemas for a project, what I want is to have independent packages, and a shared package. please see the example below.

```
// file: shared.proto
syntax = "proto3";
package package.shared;

message Address {
    string line = 1;
    string city = 2;
    string state = 3;
    string country = 4;
    uint32 zip = 5;
}
```

```
// file: invoice.proto
syntax = "proto3";
package package.invoice;

import "./shared.proto";

message Invoice {
    // some fields
    shared.Address address = 1;
}
```

```
// file: customer.proto
syntax = "proto3";
package package.customer;

import "./shared.proto";

message Customer {
    // some fields
    shared.Address address = 1;
}
```

I tried the above approach to design what I needed however, it's not working, getting the error `Import Error: ./shared.proto is not found or has some error`

Right now, I'm duplicating the shared fields with Invoice and Customer as a work around, I will be generating these `protobuf`'s for TypeScript and Java once complete.

If anyone knows a proper solution, please answer.

***Note: This question is not a duplicate question, I tried to find import and shared package-related documents or answers, but still no luck.***

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little gnarly.

Think of protobuf packages like namespaces in your preferred programming language.

Generally, you want to reflect the package structure via the folder structure.

I tend to root my protos in a folder called `protos`. I'm using `foo` rather than `package` because `package` is a reserved name and could be problematic:

```bash
.
└── protos
    └── foo
        ├── invoice
        │   └── invoice.proto
        └── shared
            └── address.proto
```

The folder names should match the package (!) path (`foo.invoice`, `foo.shared`) while the file names generally reflect the message name.

`invoice.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package foo.invoice;

import "foo/shared/address.proto";

message Invoice {
    foo.shared.Address address = 1;
}
```

`Invoice` in package `foo.invoice` must reference `Address` by its fully-qualified package name `foo.shared.Address`.

`address.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package foo.shared;

message Address {
    string line = 1;
    string city = 2;
    string state = 3;
    string country = 4;
    uint32 zip = 5;
}
```

Then, using `protoc`:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/protos \
--java_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/protos/foo/shared/address.proto \
${PWD}/protos/foo/invoice/invoice.proto
```

Because we've a single root (`${PWD}/protos`) for the protos we're using, we can using a single `--proto_path=${PWD}/protos` to anchor the set.

It's necessary to fully specify the path (including the root) to each of the protos that we want to compile.

Produces:

```bash
.
├── foo
│   ├── invoice
│   │   └── InvoiceOuterClass.java
│   └── shared
│       └── AddressOuterClass.java
└── protos
    └── foo
        ├── invoice
        │   └── invoice.proto
        └── shared
            └── address.proto
```

Comment: Thanks, @dazwilkin for your answer, I suppose there is no way to use a proto file directly, we must generate java files or js/ts files? I was using a `protobuf` CDN to load .proto file directly.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't reference protobuf files via URLs if that's what you mean. It would be neat but it's not possible.

Comment: As expected, I spend a whole day just to understand that, thanks again @DazWilkin